# ASP.NET Entity FrameWork связи двух таблиц

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

[image: Пример БД]

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста. Пытаюсь сформировать модель и контроллер, чтоб при запросе на выходе выдавал ответ в json'e, а именно в формате:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Название темы",
      "discription": "Тут какой либо текст",
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "login": "admin"
      },
      "adress": "ул. Пермская"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Название темы",
      "discription": "Тут какой либо текст",
      "author": {
        "id": 2,
        "login": "Oleg"
      },
      "adress": "ул. Пермская"
    }
  ]
}
```

Вот модели которые описал в одном классе

```
[Table("points")]
    public class point
    {
        [Key, Column("id_p")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string discription { get; set; }
        public int author { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("user")]
    public class user
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string photo { get; set; }
    }

    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class pointContext : DbContext
    {
        public pointContext() : base("conn")
        { }

        public DbSet<point> points { get; set; }
        public DbSet<user> users { get; set; }
    }
```

Сама БД как заметили MySQL

Comment: И с чем у вас вопрос, что именно вы не понимаете? Как сделать запрос к БД знаете? Или вы не знаете, как полученные данные отдать в формате Json? Если второе, то у контроллера есть не только return View или return RedirectToAction -- но ещё и return Json. Вот и всё собственно. Ну и нугет-паркет Json.Net подключите для быстрого формирования json.

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю как обратиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть контекст, используйте его для получения данных из БД:

```
    using(pointContext db = new pointContext())
    {
        user user = db.users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.login == "admin"); // получение пользователя с логином admin
        List<point> points = db.points.ToList(); // все значения из таблицы points
        List<point> pointsByUser = db.points.Where(e => e.author == user.id).ToList(); // значения из таблицы points для конкретного пользователя
    }
```

Получаете данные, записываете в объект, который описывает ваш json и сериализуете в json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
jsonObject jsObj = new JsonObject();
...
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsObj);
```

Comment: Записей в таблице points может быть много. И пользователя получать нужно в зависимости от того какая запись выводится из таблицы points (имеется связь между points.author и user.id)

Comment: @ivleb Вам привели лишь примеры запросов, ориентируясь на которые вы можете уже дальше сконструировать себе нужное. Вопрос был ваш был именно о том как в целом делается (я уточнял у вас в комментарии), вам показали базовые примеры в EF, дали пару примеров linq-выражений. Этот ответ верный и я рекомендую его принять галкой слева от вопроса.

Comment: @ivleb Сейчас же вы задаёте _другой_ вопрос, уже более конкретный, вам нужно записать какой-то конкретный `Where`, что-то подключить через `Include` и так далее. Ясно, что теорию вам читать неохота и разбираться сами вы не хотите -- но задавайте _отдельный_ вопрос, можно даже сделать из нового ссылку в старый чтобы не копипастить часть текста. Вам ничего не мешало этот конкретный вопрос СРАЗУ вписать в исходную постановку задачи: что спрашиваете -- то и попадает в ответ, а многократно в комментариях перезадавать вопрос "а ещё и вот это и вот это" -- это моветон.